# How can I maximize optimization using gcc?

Tags: gcc, optimization, compiler-optimization

I made a simple quick sort algorithm using C language, named test.c 
I'm trying to maximize the optimization, so I use -O3 options like belows.

```
gcc -S -O3 -o test.s test.c
gcc -S -O3 -o test1.s test.s
gcc -S -O3 -o test2.s test1.s
gcc -S -O3 -o test3.s test2.s
.
.
.
```

But strange thing happens. The more times I did above procedure, the more number of line assembly get.

I don't know why this happens, because I think that I have to get more optimized assembly file that has smaller number of line as I did above procedure.

If this is not right way, using -O3 only one time is the way of the best optimization?

Thanks

Comment: Which version of GCC? My GCC 4.9.2 will not create a new assembly file at all when the source is already in assembly...

Answer (score 1):

Most of the gcc optimizations operate on the representation of C source code in an intermediate language. I'm not aware of any optimization specifically operating at the assembler instruction level other than *peephole*. But that would also be included in `-O3`.

So yes, `-O3` is supposed to be used only once, when turning C source into object files.